# Почему у меня метод возвращающий массив факториалов вместо чисел 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго вечера. Мне нужно сделать следующее задание:
Создать абстрактный класс “AClass” у которого будет свойство “Numbers” типа Array, который будет содержать n натуральных чисел. Также AClass должен иметь метод “fill”, который заполняет массив Numbers случайными числами; метод “factorial”, который возвращает
массив факториалов из массива Numbers.
Я написал следующий код, метод fill выводит вместо чисел undefined.Помогите,пожалуйста, разобраться.

```js
/**
 * Abstract Class Aclass.
 *
 * @class Aclass
 */
 class Aclass {

    constructor(numbers) {
      if (this.constructor == Aclass) {
        throw new Error("Abstract classes can't be instantiated.");
      }
this.numbers = numbers;
    }
  
    fill() {
      return this.numbers.from({length: 40}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40));

    }


    factorial() {
        var facArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.fill().length; j++) {
            let num = this.fill[j];
            if (num === 0 || num === 1)
                return 1;
            for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                num *= i;
            }
            facArray.push(num);
        }
  
        console.log(facArray);

    }




    


    sort() {
        throw new Error("Method 'sort()' must be implemented.");
    }
  }

  class Class1 extends Aclass{
    sort() {
        console.log('sort'); 
    }
  }
  class Class2 extends Aclass{
    sort() {
        console.log('sort'); 
    }
  }

  const a =new Class1(Array);
  //console.log(a);
a.fill();
a.factorial();
```

Comment: Работает у тебя всё просто вызов сделай так console.log(a.fill()); А undefined у тебя выводит console.log(facArray); внутри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь for (var j = 0; j < this.fill().length; j++) { let num = this.fill[j];...

Ты на каждой итерации вызываешь this.fill() потом пытаешься взять this.fill[j] чего в природе не существует. Даже если ты вызовешь this.fill()[j] то каждый раз у тебя будет браться число из нового массива this.fill() по текущему индексу.. Пример с переделанным factorial()

> метод fill выводит вместо чисел undefined

Ну а метод fill у тебя работает нормально

```js
/**
 * Abstract Class Aclass.
 *
 * @class Aclass
 */
 class Aclass {

    constructor(numbers) {
      if (this.constructor == Aclass) {
        throw new Error("Abstract classes can't be instantiated.");
      }
this.numbers = numbers;
    }
  
    fill() {
      return this.numbers.from({length: 40}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40));

    }


    factorial() {
        var facArray = [], fil = this.fill();
        
        function fctrl(num) {
          if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
              return 1;
          }
          return num * fctrl(num - 1);
        }
        function getF(arr) {
            var result = arr.map(x => fctrl(x));
            return result;
        }
        return getF(fil)
    }




    


    sort() {
        throw new Error("Method 'sort()' must be implemented.");
    }
  }

  class Class1 extends Aclass{
    sort() {
        console.log('sort'); 
    }
  }
  class Class2 extends Aclass{
    sort() {
        console.log('sort'); 
    }
  }

  const a =new Class1(Array);
  //console.log(a);
console.log(a.factorial());
//console.log(a.fill());
```

Здесь я добавлю имитацию того что происходит в цикле for но длина массива будет изменятся случайно на каждой итерации это просто для примера и ясности того, как отрабатывает for ..

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}

function Create() { 
 x = []; 
 for (var i = 0; i < rand(0,10); i++) { 
   var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * 101);
   x[i] = j; 
 }  
 return x
}

let n = Create();

for (var i = 0; i < Create().length; i++) {
   console.log(Create[i],Create()[i]);
}
console.log(n)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На здоровье! :)